# How to select/query effectively 70,000 json data?

Tags: javascript, json, large-data-volumes

I'm now developing javascript library which consists 70,000 more villages in Indonesia (accessible at http://bisbak.com/regina/) and I build a data browser widget. Everything is fine in Safari and Firefox. But when using Chrome, it always takes long when I happen selecting a district (which automatically loads villages). The code to retrieve district's villages is like:

```
for (n in data) {
  var rs = [];
  if (n is ok) rs.push(data[n]);
  return rs;
}
```

data is json object with more than 70,000 village keys.

Comment: Please supply a small example of the data object and do you have the possibility to refine the query by alphabet or number of results (pagination)?

Comment: Here is how the village data are stored:

data:{
  1205060020:["Parbaju Toruan", 1],
  1205060021:["Hapoltahan", 1],
  ...
}

The first 7 digit is actually the id of the village parent which is a district and it is used as query argument.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should load the data only when necessary.

In your case you could load only *Provinsi* on startup. And when one *Provinsi* item is selected, you only load all *Kab./Kota* items that belong to it; and when one *Kab./Kota* item is selected, you only all *Kecamatan* items that belong to it, and so on.

To improve the performance, you could load two levels instead of one. So when a *Provinsi* item is selected, you load all *Kab./Kota* items and the *Kecamatan* that belong to it. Additionally, cache the data on the client and server side.

Comment: I think i already did it that way. A group of villages is only constructed/loaded when a Kecamatan (district) selected. I don't know which part of the code that slows the query when running on Chrome. On Safari and Firefox I never get noticeable delay, even if I add properties for each object (like population, post code, etc).

Comment: @Muslax: Receiving */regina/regina-desa-bps.js* does take most of the time (see http://tools.pingdom.com/?url=http://bisbak.com/regina/).

Comment: Yes, it's 2MB or more. But even when I tested offline, Chrome stucks for more than 8 seconds. Is there any JS data size limitation? Or do you think there's something else could be done? Thanks.

Comment: @Muslax: But why should all the 2 MB be loaded when only a small percentage is needed?

Comment: I want all data ready at client side. It is presented as tree-like. We have 33 provinces, 400+ regencies, 6000+ districts and 70000+ villages. Typically (as in my data browser widget) user can select one object at a time (and gets bonus: the children of this object). It's just like file system finder/explorer. But even if a district (3rd level object) has a few villages, Chrome always stucks. In Safari and Firefox, my code runs well even when I call a function that returns all (70000+) villages.